# how to use result from parent class object in multiple classes

Tags: java, polymorphism

i edited the post to be a bit more clearer.
in my program i have two .java files.

**IoInterface.java** in which i ultimately want to create some methods that give back a boolean result. see below (this is just to simulate a result):

```
   public class IoInterface{
   //let just say reading a button press that return true
     public boolean getDigitalInput(){
       boolean result = true;
       return result;
     }
   }
```

the next one is **StateMachine.java**.
in this one i go through several states.
in each state i would like to acces the result from getDigitalInput() for example.

```
public class StateMachine extends IoInterface  {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        IoInterface io = new IoInterface();

        State.firstState = new firstState();
        State.secondState = new secondState();
        State.thirdState = new thirdState();

    //on startup move to first state
    State.currentState = State.firstState;

    while (true) {
      State.currentState.enter();
      State.currentState.update();
    }
  }
}


// code starts in this state
class firstState extends State {
 // here i need to read the result from IoInterface.java -> getDigitalinput method
 // bool buttonPress= io.getDigitalInput();  this doesnt work

 void enter() {
// while in this state do something
}

 void update() {
//move to new state if button is pressed
 if (buttonPress = true){
currentState = secondState}
   }   
}


abstract class State {
  static State firstState, secondState, thirdState, currentState;

  void enter() {}

  void update() {}

}
```

Comment: Could you give more detail? what is the `IoInterface` class that is not `interface`, and why `StateMachine` extends `IoInterface`, why `State` has multiple `State` objects?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i edited the post with some explanation. Hope it is clearer now!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you are trying to solve is how to properly trigger one state with a signal that will help it transition to the correct state, then you will probably benefit from a blog I wrote regarding how to properly implement a state machine.

1. [Combining State and Singleton patters to create a State-Machine](https://www.professorfontanez.com/2017/04/combining-state-and-singleton-patterns.html)
2. [Using a State-Machine to Control a Wizard](https://www.professorfontanez.com/2017/04/using-state-machine-to-control-wizard.html)

In the first one, you will see how I created immutable state objects to represent finite states and use the State design pattern to control the transitions from state to state. On the second one, I expanded this implementation to use my design to control a wizard (where each "view" is a state and button clicks are the signals that trigger the transition from state (view) to another (view). Basically, the second blog puts the design in practice.

If not, you will need to clarify precisely what problem you are trying to solve. If you need a little bit of background on the State pattern, read this [article](https://www.professorfontanez.com/2017/03/real-world-application-of-state-design.html).

For your specific issue, you need to understand proper delegation of responsibilities. It is not the responsibility of the `firstState` class to know it the starting point of the application.

```
class firstState extends State {
 // here i need to read the result from IoInterface.java -> getDigitalinput method
 // bool buttonPress= io.getDigitalInput();  this doesnt work
 // The above lines do not belong here. They belong in the `IoInterface` class (or whichever class contains the button).
 void enter() {
// while in this state do something
}

 void update() {
//move to new state if button is pressed
 if (buttonPress = true){
currentState = secondState}
   }   
}
```

Comment: thank you for you fast reply, it was not wat i was looking for but i definitely have a look at it as i am just starting with java and still learning. i have edited my post to be more clear. if you can help me it would be really appreciated!

Comment: @mittens13 the functionality of your `update()` method is is precisely what my blogs regarding the State pattern are all about. The only missing piece is what the `enter()` method does. Your update is unclear. I assume that, your `IoInterface.getDigitalInput()` is mapped to a button that triggers the start of the chain of events in the State-Machine you created. In this case, this is simple: `button.click() {ioInterface.getDigitalInput();}` should be included in your real UI class. This means that you need to properly call the `IoInterface` constructor whenever you build your application.

Comment: @mittens13 have you been able to solve your problem?

Comment: sorry for the late reply but havent got the time to get back to it! so not yet. thanks for helping!